# How to solve this "NotImplementedError" urllib2 / gevent error on windows?

Tags: python, windows, urllib2, ipv6, gevent

I'm trying to open an url with urllib2 patched with gevent on Windows XP:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com")
response = opener.open(request)
```

And I get this exception during the `opener.open` call:

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\gevent\socket.py", line 768, in getaddrinfo
  sockaddr = (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, res), port, 0, 0)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\gevent\socket.py", line 133, in inet_ntop
  raise NotImplementedError('inet_ntop() is not available on this platform')
NotImplementedError: inet_ntop() is not available on this platform
<SERPScrapper at 0xbc0f60> failed with NotImplementedError
```

Looking at the gevent socket.py source code it seems to be related to IPV6 on windows...

Any idea or proposition to solve this problem ?

**edit:** I don't get the problem with other url (ie: http://www.bing.com). It seems that google is using IPV6. Is there a way to force an IPV4 response ?

Answer (score 2):

Try making your request to `http://ipv4.google.com/` instead.